# 2017 Jeep Grand Cherokee

Tags: jeep, grand-cherokee, electronic-stability-control

Driving my 2017 Jeep Grand Cherokee Ltd, 4x4 this afternoon on a sunny day, clear road conditions. All of a sudden, all the warning lights light up on the dash including one saying "Service Electronic Stability System". I totally lose all power and control - no power steering. I was able to roll off to the side of the road (thank GOD I wasn't on the highway). Was able o call AAA and get it towed to the dealership. Service is closed today. Any others have issues like this? Any idea what's going on? Wonky computer?